# Is it possible to reduce a matching to a shortest path?

Tags: matching, shortest-path

A shortest path problem can be reduced to a matching problem, for example like this:
https://tobi.rocks/2013/09/example-reduction-spp-assignment/
But I was wondering if one could also reduce a matching problem to a shortest path problem. 
With matching problem I mean the object is to create a perfect matching between 2 equally sized groups, where every matching between two individuals of these groups has a certain weight and we want to minimize this weight.